# При логирогованни в linkedIn Api произошла ошибка:

Tags: laravel

Argument 1 passed to Laravel\Socialite\SocialiteManager::formatRedirectUrl() must be of the type array, null given, called in D:\OSPanel\domains\socialite\vendor\laravel\socialite\src\SocialiteManager.php on line 125

Столкнулся с ошибкой при подключении провайдера linkedIn. 
файл: server.php

```
'linkedIn' => [
    'client_id'     => env('LINK_ID'),
    'client_secret' => env('LINK_SECRET'),
    'redirect'      => env('LINK_URL'),
],
```

роут:

```
Route::get('auth/{provider}/callback', 'Auth\LoginController@handleProviderCallback');
```

ссылка:

```
 <a href="{{ url('/auth/linkedIn') }}"...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил: прописывая всё строчными буквами ошибка исчезла.

```
'linkedin' => [
    'client_id'     => env('LINK_ID'),
    'client_secret' => env('LINK_SECRET'),
    'redirect'      => env('LINK_URL'),
],
```

роут:

```
Route::get('auth/{provider}/callback', 'Auth\LoginController@handleProviderCallback');
```

ссылка:

```
 <a href="{{ url('/auth/linkedin') }}"...
```